# is $DISPLAY set properly? - Running a wxPython Phoenix GUI in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, user-interface, xserver, wxpython

I would like to dockerize a GUI written with wxPython Phoenix in order to have the GUI appear on the host when running the docker image.

Below is a basic wxPython Phoenix GUI and the Dockerfile that creates an image with `Ubuntu 18.04`, `Python 3.7.5` and `wxPython Phoenix`.

When running the image, it returns the following message:

```
docker build -t simple-gui:latest .
docker run -it simple-gui /bin/bash
root@97229a17f2cd:~/python# ./simple_gui.py
Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?
```

I understand I have to send the address of the host's X server to the docker image that would then be used by wxPython Phoenix, but I'm not sure how to do that.

simple-gui.py: (from [wxPython Phoenix wiki](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#A_First_Application:_.22Hello.2C_World.22))

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

import wx

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World")
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install dependencies for Python and wxPython Phoenix
RUN apt update && apt install -y \
    libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev \
    libgtk-3-dev \
    libsm-dev \
    freeglut3 \
    freeglut3-dev \
    libnotify-dev \
    libgstreamer1.0-dev \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
    dpkg-dev \
    build-essential \
    python3.7-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libtiff-dev \
    libsdl1.2-dev \
    software-properties-common \
# Install Python 3.7 and pip latest versions
    && add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa \
    && apt install -y python3.7 python3-pip \
    && python3.7 -m pip install -U --no-cache-dir pip \
# Install wx
    && python3.7 -m pip install -U --no-cache-dir -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-18.04 wxPython

# Copy files
COPY simple_gui.py /root/python/
WORKDIR /root/python
ENTRYPOINT ["./simple_gui.py"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the question, the `DISPLAY` variable is used in the docker image to store the host's X server address. Depending on the host, it should take different values.

#### UNIX host (Linux/MacOS):

UNIX already uses an X server for display purposes.

1. Set a DISPLAY variable such as `DISPLAY=:0.0`.
2. Run your image with: `docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY simple-gui`

#### Windows host:

Windows does not use an X server but Windows Desktop Manager.

1. You need to install an X server for Windows, a popular choice is `VcXsrv`.
2. Set a DISPLAY variable to `DISPLAY=<HOST_IP>:0.0`, the value for `<HOST_IP>` can be found using `ipconfig`, it's the one tagged `DockerNAT`.
3. Run your image with: `docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY simple-gui` (or `DISPLAY=%DISPLAY%`, depending on your command line...)

#### Sources:

- [Run GUI app in linux docker container on a windows host](https://dev.to/darksmile92/run-gui-app-in-linux-docker-container-on-windows-host-4kde)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Mac user, you probably would have to install [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) (X server for MacOS), launch it and then run your container with `-e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0`.